# Witcher 3 The Wild Hunt won't install: Not enough disk space

Tags: the-witcher-3

I just bought The Witcher 3, and as it's installing the files, around a few minutes it says that I don't have enough Disk Space. I **clearly** do as I have over 600GB worth of space in my C Drive, where I am installing TW3

I've tried looking online to no avail. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Still not working. Would love some alternate solutions. Whenever I change disks, or even in between the download, this error occurs: Installation Failed. Error Code : -10

EDIT 2: My problem is exactly like the guy in this link: https://www.gog.com/forum/the_witcher/help_witcher_3_installation_help_retail_copy
But his solution didn't work for me. Please, someone help.

Comment: Did you buy it on GOG, Steam or physical media?

Comment: Physical Media.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it as administrator (right mouse click -> run as administrator). It worked for the guy [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/36cwx7/anyone_else_getting_not_enough_disk_space_error/crcx4zk)

Comment: I tried that before but it froze, I'll try again and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have partitions on your Hard Disc or more than one Disc in your PC?

I've Found a similar problem on the internet where the installation tries to use a Temporary Folder from a Disc with no space available. Only it was with the patch 1.07.

Here is a discussion: https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/535151589886190298/ where its last answer concerned the Temporary Folder:

> Do a hard drive test on both hard drives, just in case.
>
> Otherwise, you said you have 2 disk drives. How much space is left on
>   your other disk drive? Is that where Steam is installed? If not,
>   perhaps Steam is using system temp folder for what ever reason, and
>   you do not have enough disk space on that drive. Here are
>   instructions:
>   1. Right click on Computer and click on Properties. In the resulting window with the basic information about your computer
>   2. Click on Advanced system settings on the left panel resulting in a dialog box click on the Advanced tab a
>   3. Click on the button near the bottom labeled Environment Variables.
>   4. You may see both TMP and TEMP listed in the section labeled User variables for (account). That's the common location; each different
>   login account is assigned its own temporary location.
>   5. In the Variable value Edit box you may specify the path to the directory that Windows and many other programs will use for temporary
>   files.
>
> Be sure and repeat that process for both TMP and TEMP. You'll need to
>   restart any running programs for the new value to take effect. In
>   fact, you'll need to restart Windows for it to begin using the new
>   value for its own temporary files.

And a video about changing the temporary folder:

and the installation working.

Hope it helps

Comment: I did this, and it worked till disk 3. Then when I entered disk three, the error came once again. Goddamnit, now I have to do it again. It was 2/3 away..

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer myself, if anyone is experiencing this problem with the retail version, I suggest you do the following:

- **Enter your Game Code (back of the manual) on the GOG Client or Browser**
- **Once you enter, you will receive a receipt to your email. Keep it (it's important).**
- **Now if you do not have the GOG Client (Galaxy Client), download it.**
- **TW3 Will now appear in your Order History, you can now install it via the client**

You will now not need to install from the three disks.

Hope this helped everyone!

Comment: Please mark this as the preferred solution, then.